# I have to show $E_{11}$ is always a minimal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

For a matrix $A\in M_n(F)$, the centralizer of $A$, denoted by $C(A)$ , is the set of all matrices in $M_n(F)$ commuting with $A$. and a matrix  $A$ is minimal if for every $X\in M_n(F)$ with $C(A)\supseteq C(X)$ it follows that $C(A)=C(X)$.I have to show $E_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is always a minimal matrix.